# iOS: ensure User has to input password before In-App purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, settings

> One of the cool unsung new features of iOS 6 is the way it doesn’t ask you for a password every single time you go to make an app purchase.
>   ( http://www.cultofmac.com/201559/re-enable-password-check-in-ios-6-to-avoid-nasty-in-app-purchase-surprises-ios-tips/#LasCHqVOtcTZxIjc.99 )

I'm writing an App for Children for a client, is there a way to ensure the user has to add his password for every in-app purchase from inside the App?

I mean, I can also show a message to the parents to change the setting, but maybe that's not what they want. Still their children shouldn't be able to buy things in the ensuing 15minutes after the parents bought something from my app.

Thanks for your help!

PS: Maybe if I could read the time since the last in-app purchase somehow and check if it's less then the 15 minutes I could show an extra alert.

Comment: I have no idea about the answer but I'd like to commend you and your client for your integrity!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you can't affect this setting via API. It make sense 'cause it may have lots of security issues. Have you consider put another alert made by you before the inApp? I did the same for a kids game... I know it's a weak solution but still better than nothing

Comment: Yeah, that's the fallback we'll go for if we can't find a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS API for In App purchases does not have an option to force asking for the password. I totally understand why you would want that but it just one possible with the current SDK. I also do not see Apple changing this any time soon.

It's not even your responsibility if you look at how Apple setup the In App purchases since iOS 5. Parent can just lock the ability to use in app purchases for the device it self.

You can of course make parents aware of this ability but you just can't force it.